# Can a PPPoE only router be connect with a Static IP?

Tags: router, static-ip, pppoe

I've recently got a ZTE ZXHN H298N and I've tried to configure it. But when I get to the network configuration, I see that it doesn't let me choose anything but a PPPoE connection. Meanwhile, my ISP uses Static IP configuration and I can't use it. I've searched all around the web but nobody seems to have this problem.

My question is if there is any possibility to use it and configure it somehow, or should I just throw it away? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: ZTE ZXHN H298N has different "users", different logins. Typically a "user" level user that can only see the settings and another one, "admin" for expert mode.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "ZTE ZXHN H298N static ip" brought me to [this page](http://m.setuprouter.com/router/zte/zxhn-h298n-digi/screenshots.htm) (the site has some basic guides too) with images like these that look promising:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can you get to those pages, under Network -> Routing(IPv4) & (IPv6) and change the WAN connection type, or try adding an address & info? Or are those the pages that're giving you trouble?

That site also has a list of [common ZTE default passwords](http://m.setuprouter.com/router/zte/passwords.htm), maybe MichaelBay's right and logging in as admin (with admin password) might work, or a blank name & password, or "none" for both, or blank name & "admin" pw, etc. Or there's always the reset button to try (hold for about 10s)?